# De Marzi's Neovigator

Tags: ruby, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to use De Marzi's Neovigator
(https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neovigator)
and I'm not very successful with that.
I actually followed all the steps to install.

When I run the "neovigator.rb" file ("ruby neovigator.rb"), just nothing happens.

How do i run this, so i got the graph on a html page as a result.

Sry if I sound like I newbie, because I really am one in ruby.

Thanks a lot and Greetings

Schakron

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're supposed to run `neovigator.rb`.  The instructions say to run `rackup`.  I just went through the steps from the README and it's working

Keep in mind though that it's installing neo4j 1.9.4 which is a relatively old version considering how much neo4j has been developing over the last couple of years.

EDIT:

Posting instructions from the `README` here to make sure we're on the same page:

```
git clone git@github.com:maxdemarzi/neovigator.git
cd neovigator
bundle
rake neo4j:install
rake neo4j:start
rackup
```

Comment: ok, thanks! If I try the `rackup` command, I get an error for `neography` and `sinatra/base` requirements. Don't you get these?

Comment: I didn't.  Did you run `bundle`?  Can you share the full message/backtrace if that doesn't work?

Comment: I've updated the code and it should be working now.  Browse to localhost:9292 to see it once you follow the steps. Also the demo is available on https://neovigator.herokuapp.com/